# Ambiguity in question mark for regex and prepared statement placeholder of Laravel 5.1

Tags: mysql, regex, laravel, prepared-statement

Working in Laravel 5.1
I need to get the data for this query :

```
$query = "top";
$data['rawQuery'] = "category_names REGEXP '(?<![a-zA-Z])".'{?}'.'((es)?|(s?))(?![a-zA-Z])';
 $data['bindParams'] =  [$query];
 $result = DB::table($this->table)
                    ->whereRaw($where['rawQuery'], isset($where['bindParams']) ? $where['bindParams'] : array())
                    ->select($selectedColumns)
                    ->get();
```

I am unable to put my bind param to proper position which should be like this:

```
 select * from product_categories where category_names REGEXP '(?<![a-zA-Z])top((es)?|(s?))(?![a-zA-Z])
```

Whereas I am getting this:

```
select * from product_categories where category_names REGEXP '(tops<![a-zA-Z]){?}((es)?|(s?))(?![a-zA-Z])
```

**The difference is that , my query value is setting to wrong place.
Please show some light on this .**

Comment: Even if you set it at the proler place, REGEXP in MySQL does not support lookarounds.

Comment: Try `'[[:<:]]".'{?}'.'(es|s|)[[:>:]]'` or `'(^|[^a-zA-Z])".'{?}'.'(es|s|)([^a-zA-Z]|$)'`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to match a word that optionally ends with `s` or `es`. While that does not account for other possible endings, you might be looking for a whole word option, the word boundaries. In MySQL, you need to use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`. Note that the optional endings can be defined via a grouping construct with alternatives - `(es|s|)`.

```
$data['rawQuery'] = "category_names REGEXP '[[:<:]]".'{?}'.'(es|s|)[[:>:]]';
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, In mysql command line I am able to get the data from database using my query. My problem is with prepared statement placeholders. Do I have to use this "[[:<:]]" and "[[:>:]]" for proving the expressions ? If yes how will I bind the params.

Comment: There is only 1 `?` here, it will get replaced with the search item.